# Pass a button element into callback function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I'm trying to pass a button element to the second function upon completion of first function.
I've stepped through it with the debugger tool and the *ele* button being passed into the callback function is being passed correctly.
However, the button element being passed in *runThisSecond* is returning undefined. Any ideas as to why that might be?

HTML file:

```
<button type="button" class="btn fruitbtn" data-fruitname= "@item.FruitName">   Add Fruit </button>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("$table#Results").on('click', '.fruitbtn', function() {
  runThisSecond(runThisFirst($(this)));
})
    
function runThisFirst (ele, callback) {
        swal({ 
            html:true,
            title: "Fruits"
        },
            function(isConfirm) {
                callback(ele);    //button element is correctly passed in here
            }
        )
    }
    
    function runThisSecond(ele) {
        var button = ele;    //This is returning undefined
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean to be passing `runThisSecond` as the callback to `runThisFirst`? If so, I think it should be like this: `runThisFirst($(this), runThisSecond)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you're currently passing to `runThisSecond` is the value returned from `runThisFirst`, which is nothing (`undefined`). If you want `runThisSecond` to act as the `callback` parameter in `runThisFirst`, you'll need to pass it as the second argument:

```js
runThisFirst($(this), runThisSecond)
```

Comment: No problem, callbacks are magical until you realize you're just passing a function to another function as an argument!